# Altium PDF exporter throws all nets off-center

Tags: altium, software

I have a schematic I am exporting to PDF to send.  However, when I use the SmartPDF or export through an outjob Altium moves all net names, port names, and pin names to the left.  Am I missing some setting that is doing this, or is there something about my schematic that would cause this?  I cannot find anyone else who has had this problem in searching.  I have attached an example of what is happening.

[image: Centered]
[image: Offset]

Comment: Please Check Fit to page in the printer dialog. The schematic must be the same size of your page.

Comment: The problem is with exporting to pdf.  Although this problem also exists when I try to print it.  Fit to page is selected in that dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having Altium exports that look like below.

This fixed it for me...

DXP->Preferences->Schematic->General->Render Text with GDI+ and uncheck Render Text with GDI+

[image]

Comment: Yup, this was it!  Accepting the answer in case anyone has this problem in the future.